# jQuery .css not working in chrome but works in FF, Safari, IE9

Tags: jquery, css, forms, google-chrome, hide

I've been trying to get a better grasp on jQuery and have been coming up with random pages to test some of it. I made a small mock travel agency page that has a form with options for origin and destination countries. The default origin/destination is the US, and a second option for the States appears underneath it. When the user chooses something other than the US, the states option disappears, except in Chrome.

website: http://www.stephenweigel.com/portfolio/somewheresomehow

Script: (does have $(document).ready(function() , didn't think I needed to post the whole JS file)

```
 $('#destination').click(function(){
            // Show US States if Destination is US
            var destination = $('#destination').val();
            var domestic = 'USA';

            if (destination == domestic) {
                $('#usDest').css("display","inline");
            } else {
                $('#usDest').css("display","none");
            }
```

html:

```
<div>
      <select name="destination" id="destination">
        <option value="USA" selected="selected">USA</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
         <option value="France"> France </option>
        <option value="Spain"> Spain </option>
      </select> <!--end destination-->
     </div>
     <div>
     <select name="usDest" id="usDest">
        <option value="Alabama" selected="selected">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
            <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
            <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
            <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
            <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
            <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
            <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
            <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
            <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
            <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
      </select> <!-- end usDest-->
      </div>
```

Maybe I'm missing something but it seems strange that it would work for Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer 9 but wouldn't work in chrome.

I've also tried using:

```
  $('#origin').click(function(){
            var origin = $('#origin').val();
            var domestic = 'USA';

            if (origin == domestic) {
                $('#usOrigin').removeClass("invisible");
                $('#usOrigin').addClass("visible");
            } else {
                $('#usOrigin').removeClass("visible");
                $('#usOrigin').addClass("invisible");
            }
```

with the css:

```
.visible {
    display: inline;

}

.invisible {
    display: none;  
}
```

but that doesn't work either in chrome. (works in other browsers)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: My Chrome hides and shows the States successfully.

Comment: this is works for me. When I select another country - the state form control disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use `hide()` and `show()` to accomplish this effect with jQuery. But based, on what people are posting here, I'm guessing you're having a problem with [JS propagation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html&ei=X4W2T_KBGYum8QSpgIHHCg&usg=AFQjCNHBzjK5MxmBx8E0A3Pl40grLbcDEA&sig2=yVv8ycMIqsz06SeLcAWAYg) (an error in the code). This could be caused by a faulty extension, which is why you're getting it, and no one else is. Test your app in `Incognito Mode` to easily and temporarily disable extensions. Launch Incognito Mode in Chrome with `CTRL + SHIFT + N`

Comment: It must be something with my Chrome browser. I tried Incognito Mode and it still didn't work. But tried it on another computer and it seems to work. I'll reinstall chrome and see if it makes a difference.

But I'll keep the hide() / show() in mind for next time. Thanks.

Comment: No errors show up. I reinstalled chrome but it still doesn't work on my machine. Tried both the hide()/show() and the answer kalisjoshua provided and they both worked in other browsers and in chrome on another computer. 

When I click on the country option and choose another country it stays a darker grey for a few seconds, like it's working on something, but nothing actually happens. 

Not really sure what to make of it at this point. I guess the answer is the code is fine, there's just something wrong with chrome on my computer.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for Chrome on my laptop either. So maybe it's an OSX Chrome thing? Since it works on the PC I tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/XzQkb/.

```
<div>
    <select name="destination" id="destination">
        <option value="USA" selected="selected">USA</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
        <option value="France"> France </option>
        <option value="Spain"> Spain </option>
    </select> <!--end destination-->
</div>
<div>
    <select name="usDest" id="usDest">
        <option value="Alabama" selected="selected">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
        <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
        <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="California">California</option>
        <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
        <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
        <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
        <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
        <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
        <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
        <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
        <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
        <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
        <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
        <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
        <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
        <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
        <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
        <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
        <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
        <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
        <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
        <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
        <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
        <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
        <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
    </select> <!-- end usDest-->
</div>​
```

and

```
$("#destination").on("change", function () {
    $("#usDest").toggle($(this).val() === "USA");
});​
```

Comment: It works, but doesn't solve the problem I was having in chrome. I think the issue is not the code, it's the computer. But that's for the response, I hadn't thought of writing it that way, I"ll keep that in mind for future projects

Comment: I am working in Chrome on Mac for all of this. I created the fiddle in Chrome on Mac and it works fine for me. Does the fiddle work for you?